# How to show only part of picture's width in ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

I have Image in ImageView which is very wide since I use it as a animated background. How can show picture so that its height fills whole parent and width is displayed as much as screen is wide?

I tried making this with this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but it doesn't work. It just shows whole picture inside of screen, resizing it's width to screen's one. Where am I mistaking?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried something like this:

[How to display a part of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466297/how-to-display-a-part-of-an-image)

or you can use the android scaling

```
 Use android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

Comment: I made it up with "centerCrop", but unfortunately I lose image with that, so when I want to make translation on x axis, I have only part of picture which is in center.