# Android customimageview like whatsapp?

Tags: android, imageview

I want to display image like whatsapp first display half image when user click on image in popup display full image i have all square images but image should be display half

Example :

Required Imageview Like This :

[image]

What is current display

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use following line of code in your xml to display only center part of image in your imageview

`android:scaleType="centerInside"`

[this will help you another way to crop and display image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466297/how-to-display-a-part-of-an-image)

Comment: no my image is square and if i am trying this than left and right side blank space is coming i want to fill parent witdth but height is ( width /2 )

Answer (score 0):

You may use below line in your xml

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```